# Using a mix of SSD1306 and SH1106 displays within an Arduino application

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have an Arduino project which deploys 0.96" OLED displays.
For a new device I want to use the 1.3" OLED display, however, the 0.96" are SSD1306 and the 1.3" SH1106.

Is it possible to declare the display and then initiate it according to the actual display deployed (I can specify a parameter send by the server).

E.g. rather than:

```
SSD1306Wire display;
```

I was going to declare it as:

```
OLEDDisplay display;
```

And then initialise with:

```
display = SSD1306Wire(0x3c, 4, 5);
```

or

```
display = SH1106Wire(0x3c, 4, 5);
```

I am coming from the Java world, and declaring an abstract class is allowed.
But with Arduino I get:

> cannot declare variable 'display' to be of abstract type 'OLEDDisplay'

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I realise that I need to use a pointer of the abstract class and assign the chosen display driver to the pointer.